# Comparing fields only when NOT null

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a query like this.

`SELECT T1.timestamp, T2.timestamp FROM (SELECT …) AS T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ….) AS T2 ON T1.id = T2.id WHERE T1.timestamp < T2.timestamp`

The problem I am facing is that the condition `WHERE T1.timestamp < T2.timestamp` will filter out rows where T1.timestamp < T2.timestamp as well as rows where T2.timestamp is null.

In my use case I don't want the query to filter out rows where T2.timestamp is null. `T1.timestamp < T2.timestamp` should compare only if both timestamps are defined and should return rows where T2.timestamp is null.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: `WHERE T1.timestamp < T2.timestamp OR T2.timestamp IS NULL` doesn't qwork out for you?

Comment: I tried that and it works. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: WHERE T1.timestamp<= ifnull(T2.timestamp,T1.timestamp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying N.N. answer here so the question doesn't show up with 0 answers:

```
WHERE T1.timestamp<= ifnull(T2.timestamp,T1.timestamp)
```

And Pentium10 answer:

```
WHERE T1.timestamp < T2.timestamp OR T2.timestamp IS NULL
```

(I'll delete this answer if N.N. or Pentium10 move their comments to an answer)